# How do I use mysql compress() / uncompress() with hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, compression

How do I use mysql's compress() and uncompress() functions to compress text before I store it and uncompress it when I retrieve it using a mysql database with hibernate for ORM?

Answer (score 6):

See the [ColumnTransformer](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/ColumnTransformer.html), IIRC since 3.6:

```
@Column(name = "data", columnDefinition = "BLOB", nullable = false)
@ColumnTransformer(read = "UNCOMPRESS(data)", write = "COMPRESS(?)")
@Lob
public byte[] getData()
{
    return theData;
}
```

Comment: SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(UNCOMPRESS(COMPRESS(REPEAT('a1',9000))));

Answer (score 1):

hmm [native queries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html)?
But i dont have to tell you that your application will depend on a mysql rdbms then ;)

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be to use stored procedures instead of queries. Stored procedures [supported](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/querysql.html#sp_query) by hibernate. That's likely to get unwieldy, though.